# typings.json not getting updated typings install --ambient

Tags: angularjs, json, visual-studio-2015, definitelytyped, tsconfig

I used to work with `tsd` for managing my type definitions, but as it's deprecated, I'm trying to migrate to `typings` which is my opinion more complicated, but should be the way to go, I guess.

I want to install a type definition and for that I use the `--ambient` flag.

In **Visual Studio** I have the `typings.json` file which looks like that:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": false,
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "angular": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/angularjs/angular.d.ts#ca92a5b250433c38230b5f4138b36453862342bf",
    "jquery": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jquery/jquery.d.ts#ca92a5b250433c38230b5f4138b36453862342bf"
  }
}
```

This was automatically created when migrating from `tsd` to `typings` but now once I need a new type definition, for instance `angular-route` I use the following command:

`typings install angular-route --ambient`

This works fine, but the `typings.json` does not get updated.

What is the point and why am I missing? Why were `angular` and `jquery` both migrated to `typings.json` and when installing `angular-route`the file does not get refreshed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot --save

```
typings install angular-route --ambient --save
```

*command syntax above is now obsolete and only applicable to version 0.x*

[Link to Typings command help](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings)

---

### Update

As pointed out by @AndresM there are breaking changes in going from version 0.x to 1.x. See the documentation [Updating From 0.x to 1.0?](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings#updating-from-0x-to-10). The command syntax in @AndresM answer is the correct way to execute a typings command using DefinitelyTyped store and Typings version 1.x.

Comment: SWEET! That is what I was missing indeed and I was pretty sure I also tried this before, but yes. I think I was way too long struggling with that. thanks

Answer (score 20):

Actually in Typings 1.0 they did some breaking changes.
"ambient" is now "global". Just in case, installing from DefinitelyTyped must be explicit.

The following will install jQuery and save it to typings.json

```
typings install dt~jquery --global --save
```

See the link in Igor's answer for more info

Comment: Thanks for posting this, the documentation on how to use the sources is confusing

Answer (score 3):

Now with Typescript2.0(https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/09/22/announcing-typescript-2-0/) the global is also gone. The following will install jQuery and angular typings:

> npm install --save @types/angular @types/jquery

Your package.json will then have:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/angular": "^1.5.16",
  "@types/jquery": "^2.0.33"
}
```

Your `node_modules` directory will have `@types/angular` and `@types/jquery` directories which contain `index.d.ts` files.